# How poorly do Vitamix blenders grate/shred/slice winter squashes?

Tags: discussion

[How poorly do Vitamix blenders grate/shred/slice winter squashes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/102984/24882) pertains to just Vitamix blenders, and so is more specific than [Blender vs food processor vs juicer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34378/blender-vs-food-processor-vs-juicer).

I'm uncertain how my post pertains to ["brand recommendations"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/102984/how-poorly-do-vitamix-blenders-grate-shred-slice-winter-squashes#comment164396_102984), in view of [Good (cheaper) alternative to Vitamix Blender](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6365/24882).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the duplicate question is (basically):

> The three types of appliances you have listed have different primary uses, and best purposes, although they have some overlap in their capabilities.

This also applies to any *specific* blender (such as a Vitamix).

A question that is more specific than its duplicate isn't necessarily better. For example, we also close questions like "I left my raw chicken in my car overnight, can I cook and eat it" with a canonical food safety example. I do not see this as any different.